# Passing Parameter in URL returning NullReference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I could use some assistance with this. I have a controller action I've modified to take in a string. When I try to pass the string in the URL its still returning null. All its suppose to do is take in the string, then query based on that string and return the user's name in header tags. Do I need to modify my routes?

**Header in View**

```
<div class="nameBlock col-md-push-9">
    <h4>Welcome @ViewBag.HeaderName</h4>
</div>
```

**Controller Method**

```
public ActionResult Index(string LanID)
{
    var name =  db.UserInfoTable
                 .Where(x => x.Lan_Id == @LanID)
                 .Select(x => new UserViewModel
                 {
                     AppUserName = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName
                 }).FirstOrDefault();
    ViewBag.HeaderName = name.AppUserName;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: What URL are you using??

Comment: Need some clarity here.. `@ViewBag.HeaderName` is null in View, and not null on assignment?

Comment: localhost:(portnumber)/DevArea/Dev/Index/{LanID value}

Comment: @lloyd Correct. The LINQ statement is valid and should return a result which I've verified using LINQPAD5. When I run the view in the browser, It returns the null object reference screen, so I type in the LanID I want to test and then try to refresh the view and it continues to return a null reference error

Comment: Try this instead: `localhost:(portnumber)/DevArea/Dev/Index?LanID={value}`

Comment: @DavidG That did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @lloyd LAN ID is a string in this case because its a 10 character alphanumeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have set up your routing to do something with the `LanID` parameter, the MVC model binder won't know what to do with it. So you should either change the URL you want to use and tell MVC the name of the parameter by using a query string:

```
localhost:(portnumber)/DevArea/Dev/Index?LanID={value}
```

Or add an additional route to your configuration, for example (this is from memory so might need tweaking):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "LanID",
    url: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{LanID}",
    defaults: new 
        {
            area = "DevArea", 
            controller = "Dev", 
            action = "Index"
        }
);
```